# What is the idiom 'what more could one ask for' in American English?

Tags: american-english, dialectal-equivalent

My teacher said that this idiom would never be told by an American and is British English. What is an alternative way to say this in American English?

Comment: Check [`couldn't ask for more`](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/couldn't+ask+for+more) in TFD. It is cited as coming from `McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.`, so should be reasonably American in usage.

Comment: The Google Ngrams for "more could one ask for" for the American and British corpora show little difference.

Comment: I've got rhythm.  What more could one ask for?  Tea anyone...?

Comment: Are there even places where you could here "For what more could one ask?"

Comment: I question the premise here.

Comment: As it is now that idiom would work in American English. You might substitute 'I', 'you', or whatever other pronoun for 'one', since 'one' sounds really old-school (reference - I'm younger than 30.)

Comment: @Dan: I can't tell whether you're referring to [this](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/675020-mad-hatter-would-you-like-a-little-more-tea-alice).

Comment: @Scott - not intentionally, but it does seem to be heading that way!

Answer (score 9):

***Who could ask for anything more ?***, surely. (*I Got rhythm*. I. Gershwin)

Comment: I've heard answers given to the 'British' version, but this one is as rhetorical as it gets.

Comment: (Well, Madonna could, for one.)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqeoSUY6Qws]

Answer (score 7):

I believe your teacher is wrong. I am an American and "What more could one ask for?" sounds perfectly natural, if a bit formal. This is not one of those idioms that comes in one form that everyone uses consistently. You can substitute "anyone" or "you" or "a person" (for instance) in place of "one", and you could substitute "want" or "wish for" (again, just as examples) instead of "ask for".

Answer (score 5):

Lots of Gershwin jokes in here... but colloquially, I'd say "What more could you want?"

Comment: Gershwin as in "Who Could Ask for Anything More"?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 5):

I think its the "one" construction that would be highly unusual in colloquial American English. Rephrase it without that and you are probably OK. For example, I'm pretty sure I've heard "What more could anybody ask for?"

I've also heard @convoke's "What more could you want?", as well as "What more could you/anyone *need*?"

Comment: I don't think 'one' is much more cmmon in colloquial British English!

Comment: @Colin: there's a use of "one" when it means a certain specific person (for example, *me*), which sounds very British to me. But as a general pronoun, not so much. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+one+needs%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwhat+one+needs%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20one%20needs%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20one%20needs%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor, there's colloquial and colloquial. There are people for whom 'one' is in everyday speech. But many people would only ever use 'one' if they were trying to sound upper class, for whatever reason.

Comment: Agreed, "one" is slowly falling out of general use in British English. Most people would say "I've got a room with a view. What more could you ask for?". (That is, "you" rather than "one"). But "no-one" is still current: "No-one could ask for anything more".

Comment: I mean, just "what more could you ask for?" is probably fine.